# I have installed sublime3 for programming in c++ but after writing a simple program i am geting these following error

Tags: c++, environment-variables, sublimetext3

I have tried other similar answers on the net but none has solved my problem. 
I have also added `D:\CodeChef` to environment variables but still getting the same errors, need some help!

The following are the errors being shown...

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

[shell_cmd: g++ "D:\CodeChef\1.cpp" -o "D:\CodeChef/1" && "D:\CodeChef/1"]

[dir: D:\CodeChef]

[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\S ystem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Users\hp\python;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js;D:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin;D:\CodeChef;D:\Sublime Text 3;]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, if your shell is in one drive, you can't access another unless you explicitly `cd` into it. Try running the command while in the D drive.